# How to setup an Amazon VPC gateway without a Cisco/Juniper router?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, vpc, amazon-vpc

I would like to setup an Amazon's VPC gateway to my server. I do not have a Cisco or Juniper router, but found the [OpenSolaris VPC Gateway](http://kenai.com/projects/osolvpc), supposedly addressing this use case (see their [wiki](http://kenai.com/projects/osolvpc/pages/Home) for details).

Anyone tried to build this on Linux?

Comment: this is a relatively old post. I ended up using openvpn access server ami in vpc and setting iptables manually...

Comment: you can post your own answer or delete the question. Then it doesn't show up anymore as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using openvpn access server ami in a vpc:

http://openvpn.net/index.php?option=com_content&id=493

and

http://sysextra.blogspot.com/2011/01/creating-virtual-private-cluster-with.html

for setting the iptables or using your own openvpn server

Answer (score 1):

Using an [Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/) gateway without advanced/expensive hardware routers is meanwhile much easier, because AWS has just dropped the requirement to establish [Border Gateway Protocol (BGP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Gateway_Protocol) peerings in order to use the built in VPN connectivity, see [Amazon VPC - Additional VPN Features](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/09/amazon-vpc-additional-vpn-features.html):

> You can now create Hardware VPN connections to your VPC using static
>   routing. This means that you can **establish connectivity using VPN
>   devices that do not support BGP** such as Cisco ASA and Microsoft
>   Windows Server 2008 R2. **You can also use  Linux** to establish a
>   Hardware VPN connection to your VPC. **In fact, any IPSec VPN
>   implementation should work**. *[emphasis mine]*

The outlined reason for this change specifically highlights BGP as a previous barrier to adoption of this otherwise very appealing VPN connectivity to a VPC:

> First, BGP can be difficult to set up and to manage, [...]. Second, some firewalls and entry-level
>   routers support IPSec but not BGP. These devices are very popular in
>   corporate branch offices. As I mentioned above, this change
>   dramatically increases the number of VPN devices that can be used to
>   connect to a VPC. [...]

I couldn't agree more - accordingly, if so desired, you could drop OpenVPN now in favor of a connection between the built in Linux IPSec stack (or a dedicated package like Openswan/strongSwan) and the respective built in VPC IPSec functionality.